# How to solve uninterpreted statement problems when using typescript compiler api?

Tags: typescript, typescript-compiler-api

I am trying to inject a module
import statement by transformer.ts

(* I used ttypescript and it works,
But some statements are uninterpreted.)

and I succeeded in inserting the import statement
but the import statement that I injected
was not translated intermittently into the es5 grammar.

This is the code that I used in transfomer.

#### transformer.ts

```
let moduleName = 'infinite.js'
let variableName = ts.createUniqueName('infinite')
ctx.hoistVariableDeclaration('infinite')

// Here are just a few key codes summarised.
let importInject = ts.createImportDeclaration(
    undefined,
    undefined,
    ts.createImportClause(variableName, undefined),
    ts.createLiteral(moduleName))

sourceFile = ts.updateSourceFileNode(sourceFile, ts.createNodeArray([
    importInject,
    ...sourceFile.statements
]))
```

#### source.js

```
// Nothing before it.
```

#### source.js (injected import statement)

```
import infinite_1 from"infinite.js"
```

Code injection worked normally,
Although the compiler target option that defined es5,
But the code that I inserted is having a problem that doesn't translated.

However, if I add an import statement that
has nothing to do with the module import code
I will inject to the source code before module injection,
the translation of the code I inserted is also successful.

#### source.js

```
import module from './module'
module()
```

#### source.js (injected import statement)

```
"use strict";
exports.__esModule = true;
var infinite_js_1 = require("infinite.js");
var module_1 = require("./module");
module_1["default"]();
```

Hmm... is this compiling option problem...?
If so, which compiling options should be modified?
I don't know which code to modify... (x_x)

Have anyone ever had a problem like this?
If you know the solution, please let me know.

---

Additionally, I am currently using on a temporary solution as below.

```
let importInject = 
ts.createVariableStatement(
    sourceFile.modifiers, 
    [ts.createVariableDeclaration(
        variableName, 
        undefined, // Type
        ts.createCall(
            ts.createIdentifier('require'), 
            undefined,
            [ts.createLiteral(moduleName)]
        )
    )]
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why the following code gets emitted to es5...

```
import module from './module'
module()
```

...but this code doesn't...

```
import module from './module'
```

...is because while emitting, the compiler will remove any import declarations whose identifiers aren't used in an expression (try out that code with `tsc` and you will see this behaviour).

See ["Why are imports being elided in my emit?"](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-imports-being-elided-in-my-emit)

**Solution**

The solution is to either use one of the imported identifiers in an expression or to inject an import declaration that only imports the module for the side effects:

```
// import "./module";
let importInject = ts.createImportDeclaration(
    undefined,
    undefined, 
    undefined,
    ts.createLiteral(moduleName));
```